# Render Speed Very Slow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

I have what I think is a decent computer but when rendering a 1000 frame animation it take around 2-3 hours to do 4-5 frames. (Yes I have it set to GPU compute)

Details: 
Computer - Intel i7 6th gen, 12gb RAM, Nividia GeForce 940m
250 Samples
1080p graphics

Are my specs too low or could it be a rendering issue with optimization? I have a complex character but it doesn’t utilize complex geometry or many different textures. I’m using the latest Blender build, and the animation includes a moving camera and rotating meshes. Any ideas about how I could make the render go faster (or if anyone has technical knowledge in that case)? Can someone tell me what render settings they usually use for larger animations?

Comment: Questions about hardware and computer specs are considered off-topic.  (you can take the [tour] to see how this site works) Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and try to reformulate your question in a way that is not specific to your hardware and can be useful to others as well.

Comment: Alright I edited it thnx.

Comment: How much time does it do one frame more exactly? What is rendered? How many polygons, is there SSS, AO, caustics, multiple light bounces (e.g. in the enclosed environment)? What is node setup? Any screenshots of the scene and setup? That configuration *should* work fast but it might be perfectly fine if it doesn't - there aren't just enough details

Comment: Alright I’ll get those details and edit my question as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

#### Slow render times are perfectly normal. This stuff is *complicated*.

Still frames can take a while, and an animation is hundreds of still frames put together. Movies can take *very* long times to render, even on big supercomputers.

Comment: Any way to make it faster?

Comment: Yes, decrease the resolution. This will _dramatically_ decrease render times. You can also try switching tile ordering methods for a bit more speed.

Comment: Sorry, but what are tile ordering methods? I’m a bit new to blender :). Thanks for the info b.t.w. It really helps.

Comment: Blender doesn't render the entire image at once--it does it in sections, called tiles. If you go to Performance in the render settings, you can change the order it renders them in. (It's set to Hilbert Spiral by default, but I often change it to Center. I don't know what to set it to to increase performance, though.) This is for Cycles; I don't know if you can change it in BI.

Comment: Alright, thnx. I’ll play around with it a bit :).